# Console Style PHP Script Response Pushing and Max Time

Tags: php, push, flush

I realize the title is a bit incomprehensible, but, I am struggle on how to define what it is I am trying to accomplish.

Basically, I am creating my own photo gallery because none of the existing ones met my needs. The one part of the script loads the directory where my photos are located, and adds them to the database, loads the image tags, XMP info, etc. The problem is, it takes way too long. As a challenge, I want to do it without tampering with the max execution time.

I think would would be best is the PHP script sends notifications to the browser into a console style page. Ie, "File 3232 Processed \n, File 3233 Processed". Then using the shutdown function in before the max time, it sends a message saying to the browser that it got shutdown on file 3234 and a javascript function reloads the script starting at file 3234 through ajax or something.

My issue is I do not know how to get the PHP script to send the console style messages instantaneously. I tried various ajax load commands, but it waits for the entire script to finish, then sends a huge glob of results. I have tried the flush command and ob_implicit_flush(1) with no avail.

Links to examples or tutorials, or postings would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the other way around: send the full list of images to the browser, and the browser will make ajax requests to process specific image.

Comment: While, I do like that idea, loading the main page with the entire array of files doesn't work either as it goes over the max ex time

Comment: Will you be able to load the file list into array using glob() without timing out? This will give you ordered list and you can use offset. As I see it, you don't have the max execution time solved, right?

Comment: Actually, that works perfectly. I just finished the working script this afternoon. Thanks